# How to redirect the console output to richtextbox?

Tags: c#, .net

And because the output come from the results of a solver, will last for quite a long time, is there a way
the richtextbox could display the output simultaneously with the console?

Comment: Do you mean to route the standard output of an external process or do you have a hybrid Console/Forms project?

Comment: Clarify the application type and problem please.